# TeX formatting wrong in revision view

Tags: bug, revisions-list, latex

When viewing [my question's revisions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/244084/revisions), the TeX formatting does not switch out of math mode. It treats the text "I wonder why would it not be possible to specify" as math, for some reason. In the main question view I think it displays correctly.

This is how the revision looks:

> [image]

This is how the main question looks:

> [image]